# JetBrains Rider: Show the full method or function signatures inside "Find in Files" dialog?

Tags: rider, jetbrains-rider

When using the "Find in Files" dialog in JetBrains Rider (Ctl Shift F), is there a way to show the full method or function signatures﻿? The method/function signatures can be shown in a regular file dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Quick Documentation` is available when you hover on the methods.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhrRM.png